# Flash Builder not showing members of XML or XMLList classes

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, flash-builder

All of the sudden Flash Builder is not longer showing the members of the XML or XMLList classes for code completion. I did some experimenting by creating a brand new workspace with new empty projects (to make sure it wasn't some corruption in my main working set(s)), and it appears the bug only affects Flex projects; Flash Professional projects still work.

The Flash Builder version is current (4.6), which is based on Eclipse 3.7.

A picture will show this much more clearly:

- In a Flash Professional project: typing `.` or hitting `CTRL + Space` after the name of a variable of type `XML` brings up the member list:
  [image: Autocomplete for Flash Professional project]
- In a Flex Library project, only default `Object` members appear:
  [image: Autocomplete for Flex Libarary project]
- In a Flex project, only default `Object` members appear:
  [image: Autocomplete for Flex project]

This morning I did install some updated components of the Eclipse Web Components for editing XML and XSD files...

I did review the various tips itn [Flash Builder 4 suddenly stops doing auto-complete for some classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826249/flash-builder-4-suddenly-stops-doing-auto-complete-for-some-classes) but they don't seem to affect this situation -- particularly since it manifests in a brand new workspace with only 3 tiny projects.

**Update** I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Flash Builder. The issue remains.

Comment: We have the same situation for all the team members who work with Flash Builder 4.6, and found no solution or information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me just few minutes ago. But not with the xml. I was using flare3D and changed the swc file with the new version. Initially it was throwing error recognizing a data member (Mesh3D.surfaces) as unknown. I first thought the new version has changed name or removed the data member. However when I debugged more I found its not recognizing any data member (It was showing no data members in it). But it was working/showing in my other project which was is FB4.0 but I am not sure it is related with the FB version or not.

Then after various tries such as closing, openning, reimporting library, rebooting IDE etc., I created a fresh project (in 4.6) and copied files. That did the magic. Hopefully it works for you too.